# Express.js: how to handle "Error: ENOENT, unlink" errors?

Tags: express, error-handling, fs

I have a piece of code where I delete a file from the server. Sure, I could firstly check if file even exists and then delete it; and I've done it so. But, what really bothers me is why express.js app crashes when it wants to delete a file that doesn't exists? I get the 'Error: ENOENT, unlink'.

```
fs.unlink(path, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;

});
```

If in the above code "path" does not exists, I get the "ENOENT" error and server crashes.
I thought "server.on('error', onError);" in www file handles such errors as well. Is it possible to add such a handler?

Comment: Post a code snippet.

Comment: I did, although what I really want to know is, why express.js does not handle such errors

Answer (score 0):

So you should just handle that error there. That's the place in code that knows best how to handle it and what caused it. The broader last-resort places are `server.on('error', handler)` but that's for errors within the express HTTP service processing logic itself, not any error in the entire node process. For any error in the process there's `process.on('uncaughtException', handler)`.

> why express.js does not handle such errors

Because express is not omniscient and the correct way to handle that error is only known to you. For all express knows, crashing the process **IS** the correct behavior.